# How to draw connected circles with lines in CSS and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to connected circles with other circles using lines as connector, each circle should holds hyper link text. using CSS and html[image]

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: i dont have anything i am new

Comment: I think you may need to grok some basics before you attempt this.

Comment: Since you already have the drawing, might I suggest using this drawing for a `background-image`. Otherwise, the answer is either "no", "svg", or since your tags say Javascript, "canvas".

Answer (score 2):

As an idea to start I can propose you the following concept:

```
<style>
a {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: white;
}

#elementG {
    position: absolute;
    left: 150px;
    top: 100px;
}

#elementH {
    position: absolute;
    left: 70px;
    top: 150px;
}

#elementA {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 80px;
}

b {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    width: 70px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

#linkGA {
    -moz-transform: rotate(50deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(50deg);
    transform: rotate(50deg);
    left: 30px;
    top: 125px
}

#linkAH {
        -moz-transform: rotate(-35deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-35deg);
    transform: rotate(-35deg);
    left: 87px;
    top: 135px
}
</style>

<b id="linkGA"></b>
<b id="linkAH"></b>
<a href="#" id="elementG">G</a>
<a href="#" id="elementA">A</a>
<a href="#" id="elementH">H</a>
```

Comment: I think this is horrible, but of course, after my comment, I can't but upvote.

Comment: That is just "proof of concept" and there is no place for such a crazy trick in production.

Answer (score 1):

The sigma.js framework might be better suited than a pure css option

http://sigmajs.org/